# CONSTRAINT statements in my table creations

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

I'm looking for some help with these CONSTRAINT statements in my table creations. It looks like something simple but I'm missing it for some reason. When I try to change to add open or close parentheses within different areas of the statement, nothing seems to change.

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES (DISTRIBUTOR.DISTRIBUTOR_ID),  CONSTRAINT VIDEO_DVD_FK2 FOREIGN KEY R' at line 15
>
> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT DISTRIBUTOR_PK PRIMARY KEY (DISTRIBUTOR_ID),  CONSTRAINT DISTRIBUTOR_' at line 11
>
> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES (DISTRIBUTOR.DISTRIBUTOR_ID))' at line 25
>
> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'REFERENCES (VIDEO_DVD.VIDEO_DVD_ID))' at line 11

```
CREATE TABLE VIDEO_DVD(

VIDEO_DVD_ID   VARCHAR(100),
DISTRIBUTOR_ID   varchar(100),
MOVIE_ID   varchar(100),
CUSTOMER_ID   varchar(100),
FINE_AMT   numeric(14,0)   CHECK (FINE_AMT > 0),
DAMAGE_CHARGES   numeric(14,0)   CHECK (DAMAGE_CHARGES > 0),
TYPE   CHAR(1)   check(TYPE IN ('V','D')),
LEASE_DATE   DATE,   
RETURN_DATE   DATE   NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT VIDEO_DVD_PK PRIMARY KEY (VIDEO_DVD_ID),

CONSTRAINT VIDEO_DVD_FK1 FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES   (DISTRIBUTOR.DISTRIBUTOR_ID),

CONSTRAINT VIDEO_DVD_FK2 FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES (MOVIE.MOVIE_ID),

CONSTRAINT VIDEO_DVD_FK3 FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES (CUSTOMER.CUST_ID));
CREATE TABLE DISTRIBUTOR(

DISTRIBUTOR_ID   VARCHAR(100) ,

MOVIE_ID   VARCHAR(100),

VIDEO_DVD_ID   VARCHAR(100),

NAME   VARCHAR(1000)   UNIQUE NOT NULL

CONSTRAINT DISTRIBUTOR_PK PRIMARY KEY (DISTRIBUTOR_ID),

CONSTRAINT DISTRIBUTOR_FK1 FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES (MOVIE.MOVIE_ID),

CONSTRAINT DISTRIBUTOR_FK2 FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES (VIDEO_DVD.VIDEO_DVD_ID));
CREATE TABLE MOVIE(

MOVIE_ID   VARCHAR(100),

DIRECTOR   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,

NAME   VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,

TYPE   CHAR(1)   CHECK (TYPE IN ('C','H','S')),

DISTRIBUTOR_ID VARCHAR(100),

ACTOR_NAME   VARCHAR(100),  

LENGTH   NUMERIC(14,0)   CHECK (LENGTH > 0),

AWARDS   VARCHAR(1000),

RATINGS   NUMERIC(2,0)   CHECK (RATINGS IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)),

RELEASE_YEAR   NUMERIC(4,0),

CONSTRAINT MOVIE_PK PRIMARY KEY (MOVIE_ID),

CONSTRAINT MOVIE_FK FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES (DISTRIBUTOR.DISTRIBUTOR_ID));
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMER(

CUST_ID   VARCHAR(100),
VIDEO_DVD_ID   VARCHAR(100),
STREET   VARCHAR(1000),
ZIPCODE   NUMERIC(6,0),
ACC_NO   VARCHAR(20) UNIQUE NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_PK PRIMARY KEY (CUST_ID),

CONSTRAINT CUSTOMER_FK FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES (VIDEO_DVD.VIDEO_DVD_ID));
```

I'm using MySQL 5.7...

I was able to clear a few errors by deleting the comma at the end of the statements so I hope this will still work. I am still having these errors tho..

> 14:41:47 CREATE TABLE VIDEO_DVD( VIDEO_DVD_ID VARCHAR(100), DISTRIBUTOR_ID varchar(100), MOVIE_ID varchar(100), CUSTOMER_ID varchar(100), FINE_AMT numeric(14,0) CHECK (FINE_AMT > 0), DAMAGE_CHARGES numeric(14,0) CHECK (DAMAGE_CHARGES > 0), TYPE CHAR(1) check(TYPE IN ('V','D')), LEASE_DATE DATE, RETURN_DATE DATE NOT NULL, CONSTRAINT VIDEO_DVD_PK PRIMARY KEY (VIDEO_DVD_ID), CONSTRAINT VIDEO_DVD_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (DISTRIBUTOR_ID) REFERENCES DISTRIBUTOR.DISTRIBUTOR_ID) CONSTRAINT VIDEO_DVD_FK2 FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES (MOVIE.MOVIE_ID) CONSTRAINT VIDEO_DVD_FK3 FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES (CUSTOMER.CUST_ID)) Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT VIDEO_DVD_FK2 FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES (MOVIE.MOVIE_ID) CONSTRAINT VID' at line 17 0.016 sec
>
> 14:41:47 CREATE TABLE DISTRIBUTOR( DISTRIBUTOR_ID VARCHAR(100) , MOVIE_ID VARCHAR(100), VIDEO_DVD_ID VARCHAR(100), NAME VARCHAR(1000) UNIQUE NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DISTRIBUTOR_PK PRIMARY KEY (DISTRIBUTOR_ID), CONSTRAINT DISTRIBUTOR_FK1 FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES (MOVIE.MOVIE_ID), CONSTRAINT DISTRIBUTOR_FK2 FOREIGN KEY REFERENCES (VIDEO_DVD.VIDEO_DVD_ID)) Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT DISTRIBUTOR_PK PRIMARY KEY (DISTRIBUTOR_ID), CONSTRAINT DISTRIBUTOR_' at line 11 0.000 sec
>
> 14:41:47 CREATE TABLE MOVIE( MOVIE_ID VARCHAR(100), DIRECTOR VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, NAME VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL, TYPE CHAR(1) CHECK (TYPE IN ('C','H','S')), DISTRIBUTOR_ID VARCHAR(100), ACTOR_NAME VARCHAR(100), LENGTH NUMERIC(14,0) CHECK (LENGTH > 0), AWARDS VARCHAR(1000), RATINGS NUMERIC(2,0) CHECK (RATINGS IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)), RELEASE_YEAR NUMERIC(4,0), CONSTRAINT MOVIE_PK PRIMARY KEY (MOVIE_ID), CONSTRAINT MOVIE_FK FOREIGN KEY (MOVIE_ID) REFERENCES DISTRIBUTOR.DISTRIBUTOR_ID) Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint 1.109 sec

I am down to my last 3 errors that I still cannot get to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

```
CONSTRAINT VIDEO_DVD_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (MOVIE_ID) REFERENCES (MOVIE.MOVIE_ID),
```

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT VIDEO_DVD_FK2 FOREIGN KEY (MOVIE_ID) REFERENCES (MOVIE.MOVIE_ID),  CO' at line 17

```
CONSTRAINT DISTRIBUTOR_PK PRIMARY KEY (DISTRIBUTOR_ID),
```

Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'CONSTRAINT DISTRIBUTOR_PK PRIMARY KEY (DISTRIBUTOR_ID),  CONSTRAINT DISTRIBUTOR_' at line 11

```
CREATE TABLE MOVIE(  MOVIE_ID   VARCHAR(100),  DIRECTOR   VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,  NAME   VARCHAR(100) UNIQUE NOT NULL,  TYPE   CHAR(1)   CHECK (TYPE IN ('C','H','S')),  DISTRIBUTOR_ID VARCHAR(100),  ACTOR_NAME   VARCHAR(100),    LENGTH   NUMERIC(14,0)   CHECK (LENGTH > 0),  AWARDS   VARCHAR(1000),  RATINGS   NUMERIC(2,0)   CHECK (RATINGS IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)),  RELEASE_YEAR   NUMERIC(4,0),  CONSTRAINT MOVIE_PK PRIMARY KEY (MOVIE_ID),  CONSTRAINT MOVIE_FK FOREIGN KEY (DISTRIBUTOR_ID) REFERENCES DISTRIBUTOR.DISTRIBUTOR_ID)
```

Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint 0.453 sec

Answer (score 0):

You haven't written the column name of the foreign keys. You need to write e.g.:

```
CONSTRAINT VIDEO_DVD_FK1 FOREIGN KEY (DISTRIBUTOR_ID) REFERENCES (DISTRIBUTOR.DISTRIBUTOR_ID),
```